# Mac text editor that support LineBreak and Encoding detection/change

Tags: macos, character-encoding, editor

I'm used to windows and I try to find replacement tools in mac world.

I use Notepad++ on Windows and I frequently use the ability to detect and change the charset and the line break mode of a file.

[image: Notepad++]

I find some editor who support linebreak changing but I didn't find an editor that can display the charset of the current file and change it in an other.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes: I recommend [BBEdit](http://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/index.html) or its free smaller brother [TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/). Both are very good and both handle changes to encoding and line breaks etc well.

Comment: Thank You.I already have a look at TextWrangler (it's my actual texte editor on mac) and I miss this functionnality. I serach again and I finaly find it: Edit>Document Options

Comment: Note that the change encoding function in TextWrangler has moved to the File->Save As dialog.